# JQuery Tmpl SVG appending elements

Tags: jquery, svg, jquery-templates

Can anyone see what's wrong with the following Fiddle which is supposed to draw a dynamically generated line using SVG:

http://jsfiddle.net/paulsidebottom/Fed97/

I can see the element in the DOM but its not visible on screen.

I think the issue is to do with element namespaces but I'm not sure what the solution would be?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In firefox 8 everything works fine(Weel, it draws a square), in chrome 15 it works fine (well, it draws a circle), in IE9 i get

> https://raw.github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout.mapping/master/build/output/knockout.mapping-latest.debug.js
>   was blocked due to mime type mismatch  SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value
>   of the property 'fromJS': object is null or undefined

And so that must be the error

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned this is in Chrome and hence the squares should be rendered as circles. I edited the Fiddle a while ago to simplify this. I don't see the MIME type mismatch in Chrome and I dont think this is related because I can see in the inspection window that the element has been created in the DOM but it is not visible on screen.

Comment: I've just edited the resources on the fiddle as I the KO mapping library was being served via HTTPS - this may account for the MIME error.